# How does R's ifelse work with character data?

Tags: r

A code fragment:

```
blarg = data.frame(a=c("aa", "bb", "dd"))
blarg$b = blarg$a
# blarg$b is now c("aa", "bb", "dd")
blarg$b = ifelse(blarg$a!="bb",blarg$a,"ZZZ")
# blarg$b is now c(1, "ZZZ", 3)
# I expected c("aa", "ZZZ", "dd")
# typeof(blarg$b) is "character"
```

Why is blarg$b c(1, "ZZZ", 3)? Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: R has made `blarg$a` into a factor.  You could try `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: I don't mind it being a factor.  How do I get that same factor to come out of ifelse?

Comment: You could cast `blarg$a` to character: `ifelse(blarg$a!="bb",as.character(blarg$a),"ZZZ")` gives `c("aa", "ZZZ", "dd")`

Comment: That works.  Submit it as an answer, and I will accept it.  I find R confusing.

Comment: http://www.quantumforest.com/2011/12/r-pitfall-3-friggin-factors/ , http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf , http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-factors:factors , http://scs.math.yorku.ca/index.php/R/Traps_and_pitfalls

Answer (score 13, accepted):

+1 for using a data.frame named blarg.

To expand on what Ben said, factors are internally stored as integers so when you do something like this, R doesn't handle it the way you expect.

Take a look at `str(blarg)` in the steps of your code above.

You can either use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as Ben suggested, or make use of the factor:

```
ifelse(blarg$a!='bb', levels(blarg$a), 'ZZZ')
```

Or better yet, if you want to replace the levels of `blarg$a` that are `'bb'`, you can eliminate the `ifelse` statement altogether:

```
levels(blarg$a)[levels(blarg$a)=='bb'] <- 'ZZZ'
```