# Adding a new column to a data frame using ifelse. Why does a numeric value gets added?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add a new column to a data frame as follows:

```
stateFrame$cgroup <- ifelse(stateFrame$Freq >= 11 & 
                   stateFrame$Freq < 83, "Other",stateFrame$city)
```

So, I want if the value of frequency in the row is between 11 and 83, the new column must be assigned `Other`, else it should keep the same value as exists in another column `city` `(stateFrame$city)`.

It works fine for adding value as `other` but for all other cases,  a row number corresponding to the data frame is assigned as shown below:

[image]

What could be the reason for this? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you add `str(stateFrame)` to your question?

Comment: Google "ifelse factor coerce R site:stackoverflow.com". E.g. [How does R's ifelse work with character data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761686/how-does-rs-ifelse-work-with-character-data) and a more thorough explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669237/1851712)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your "no" input in ifelse() should be a vector and yours is most likely factor. Use `as.vector(stateFrame$city)` as follows:

```
stateFrame$cgroup <- ifelse(stateFrame$Freq >= 11 & 
                   stateFrame$Freq < 83, "Other",as.vector(stateFrame$city))
```

**Edit**
To be more precise Factor is stored as vector of integers with related character values. I think integers are returned in your code.